# cannot load such file -- mongo_mapper/document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I am receiving the following error message when attempting to authenticate with Facebook in a rails app using MongoMapper:

[image]

It appears that MongoMapper is not being loaded properly, but I am not sure why. In my Gemfile I include `gem 'mongo_mapper`, `gem 'bson_ext'`, and `gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 1.4.1'`. I also followed the setup instructions here: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html to completion. I am able to run the `$ mmconsole`, as well as connect to the mongod using the `$ mongo`. Is there another configuration step that I missing to ensure that mongo_mapper can be loaded properly? Thanks in advance for any assistance, I am new to MongoDB in general.

EDIT:

Here is what my SessionsController looks like, where the LoadError originates:

[image]